# How does shallow comparison worth with Pure Component and setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

While learning about Pure Components I haven't been able to understand the way the shallow comparison is done between complex objects e.g. the state object.

In an example a setTimeout method was used to update a simple value e.g. counter number in a state object but the value was just set to the existing value. As I understand it, setState creates a new object and doesn't mutate the original state.

So in a shallow comparison wouldn't there be 2 different state objects pointing to 2 different references even if they include a simple property with the same value, so the comparison should always show the objects as being different yet the example said that because the values are the same the component won't re-render, so does shallow comparison do more than just look at the object reference?

Comment: Please give us some context, how can we guess which example you talking about

Comment: The specific example doesn't matter, I've explained in the context of setState what the question is

Answer (score 0):

As per Documentation, shallowCompare Performs equality by iterating through keys on an object and returning false when any key has values which are not strictly equal between the arguments. Returns true when the values of all keys are strictly equal. So it won't check the reference of the state object. It will check the attributes of the state object.

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-compare.html
2. https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/e85f39ae37e9650191e832c1d1ed8f02c272e9d1/packages/fbjs/src/core/shallowEqual.js#L39-L67

Comment: Thanks, about 4 tutorials I came across only mentioned object references being compared in shallow comparison, this is what caused confusion for me. From your answer it seems the keys are being checked as well.

After reading the links I'd like to confirm if this what Pure Components are using too, as shallow-compare seems different.

Comment: The pure component is using the shallowCompare method. Additionally, it uses the `shouldComponentUpdate` method to give more control over the rendering process.